# How can I control where the error message div is displayed in CakePHP forms?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So I understand that CakePHP automatically loads the error message into the view if you validate it against the Model's validators. I am trying to setup a date dropbox validation, and I want to control where the error message shows up.

Before submitting to validate form:

```
<div class="input text required">
<label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
<input name="data[User][email]" maxlength="50" type="text" id="UserEmail">
</div>
```

After validating, error shows up here:

```
<div class="input text required error">
<label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
<input name="data[User][email]" maxlength="50" type="text" value="" id="UserEmail" class="form-error">
<div class="error-message">An email is required</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to control it where I can have it show up here?

```
<div class="input text required error">
<div class="error-message">An email is required</div>
<label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
<input name="data[User][email]" maxlength="50" type="text" value="" id="UserEmail" class="form-error">
</div>
```

Or here:

```
<div class="error-message">An email is required</div>
<div class="input text required error">
<label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
<input name="data[User][email]" maxlength="50" type="text" value="" id="UserEmail" class="form-error">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the VIEW:

1) Disable automatic error display:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Mymodel', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'error' => false
    )
));
```

2) Get the current form errors from `$this->validationErrors`

3) Display them where ever you prefer with your own markup or Cake's default markup via [$this->Form->error()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#displaying-and-checking-errors)

UPDATE:
I misunderstood your original question. The order of the elements can be specified via either the create() call (to apply to all fields) or an input() call (for an individual field):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Mymodel', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'format' => array('before', 'error', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'after')
    )
));
```

The above would place the `error` div before the `label` div. You can re-arrange that array in any order you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to utilize CakePHP's error div. It adds the error class into the div that is around around the input. How can I utilize that too?

Comment: `echo $this->Form->error('email');` Take a look at the link I posted for usage options.

Comment: I actually meant this line `<div class="input text required error">`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this for **password_confirm** field, maybe it helps

```
         echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');

        echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'div'=>'control-group',
            'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'div','class' => 'help-inline'))
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('group_id', array(
            'options' => array('2' => 'Admin', '3' => 'Publisher')
        )); 
        echo $this->Form->input('publisher_id', array(
            'options' => $publishers
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('active');
```